# SQLite Add Not Escaping Apostrophe

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am attempting to insert data using the SQLiteParameter.Add function, like this:

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO charity (trans_date, description, amount) VALUES (@trans_date, @description, @amount);";
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@trans_date", transDate));
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@description", description));
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@amount", amount));
sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Description is a string. When I use an apostrophe in description, it's not being escaped correctly. It's being inserted with two backslashes, as shown in the picture.
Can't seem to find a way to get this to work. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: BTW you should always specify the `DbType` (or provider-specific enum) when using `DbParameter` (including `SQLiteParameter`) because there is not a clean 1:1 mapping from .NET types to DB types (e.g. .NET's `DateTime` could map to any of the SQL types `date`, `datetime`, `time`, `timestamp`, etc).

Comment: **Exactly** which SQLite client library are you using? Do you have any custom `SQLiteConnection` properties set? What SQLite GUI are you using that's showing the backslashes? (Are you sure it's not intentional, or a bug, in the GUI you're using?)